# Comparing between two arrays, order matters

Tags: python, arrays, lambda, compare

week one with Python.
I would like to compare the value of two arrays where order matters and print out text. Here's what I have:

```
a =[2, 3, 4, 2, 6]
b =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

compare = map(lambda x, y: x > y, a, b)
print(list(compare))
```

and I get:

```
[True, True, True, False, True]
```

Rather than printing the list(compare) True and False I would like to print 'list a is below list b' if False. It only needs to print once if more than one False is present. I've tried many print statements without success.

```
if compare == False:
    print ('list a is below list b')
```

*nothing*

```
if compare is False:
    print ('list a is below list b')
```

*crickets*

I've tried many other ways.

Is there also a way to do a loop comparing if a>b, a>c and b>c then print('list b is below list c'). Order between lists matters. I could do the compare = map lambda 3 times but I was wondering if there's a way to loop it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check `compare` has at least one value `False`, just use the `in` operator.

```py
if False in compare:
    do action
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare 3 lists at the same time and use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all). `all()` function returns `True` iff all conditions in the iterator provided to it are `True`. -

```py
a =[2, 3, 4, 2, 6]
b =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

compare = map(lambda x, y, z: x > y and y > z, a, b, c)
print(all(compare))
```

outputs -

```
False
```

because the 3rd index is `False`.

If I update the `a` -

```py
>>> a =[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> c =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> compare = map(lambda x, y, z: x > y and y > z, a, b, c)
>>> print(all(compare))
True
```